# How to start a bash script with a particular word (TextChangedListener), in Android

Tags: java, android, bash, shell, kotlin

I have designed a foreground application with accessibility and now I want to add a feature that whenever the user types a particular word say example HELP at any application For Example google or any notepad then a bash script would be executed

I got to know that bash script or adb shell commands can be executed with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand);`

now please help me figure out how can we use it whenever a particular word is typed at any application in android (and also help me in which class I should write the code and things I need to import)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a keylogger/listener that can execute your command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).